# How to separate attributes of sqlite cursors' result

Tags: python, flask

```
    @app.route('/personal',methods=['GET'])
    def personal(name):
        return render_template('personal.html', user=name)
    
    @app.route('/error',methods=['GET'])
    def error():
        return render_template('error.html')
    
    @app.route('/login',methods=['POST'])
    def login_post():
        error = None
        result = loginf(request.form['email'], request.form['password'])
        if len(result)!=0:
            return redirect(url_for('personal', name=result))
        else:
            return render_template('login.html')
def loginf(user_email,user_pass):
    connection = sql.connect('user.db')
    connection.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(email CHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, password CHAR(30) NOT NULL);')
    connection.commit()
    cursor = connection.execute('SELECT * FROM buyers, users WHERE email=(?) AND password = (?) AND buyer_email= email', (user_email,user_pass))

    return cursor.fetchall()
```

Here's the html code:

```
    {% for email, first_name, last_name, gender, age, home_address_id, billing_address_id in user %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ email, first_name, last_name, gender, age, home_address_id, billing_address_id }} </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

im confused about how can i separate the attributes inside of the cursor since for now i'm getting everything inside the result, and i have vert few experience with python so im really confused.

Comment: So you have filtered the database already, and you have a cursor which contains the result. How would you want to separate it? Do you want to access the result's email, buyer email, and etc?

Comment: yeah, for now when i try to use it separatly in html, it says that "not enough values to unpack (expected 7, got 1)"

Comment: Have you tried {% for i in user %} {{i.email}} {% endfor %}

Comment: I have tried it but there was nothing showing up :<

Comment: Dear OP, reviewer, always explain only those things which are related to question, not tell commentaries such as `i am very new to this technology, I am trying to learn, I have to be best etc.` and don't add any thankful messages like `thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated, if someone help me it would be great or appreciated etc.`.

Comment: How about doing {% for i in user %} {{i[0]}} {% endfor %}

Comment: It didn't work as well, i'm really confused since last time i used same strategy with a simplier program and it worked